# Printing from HP-UX v11.11 via LPD Protocol (Port 515) to CUPs queue on Ubuntu Server 12.04 i386 does not work

Tags: printing, lpd

i was migrating my old document composition software from SLES9 to Ubuntu Server 12.04 i386.

Everything was working fine until I tried to print from the ERP Environment (HP-UX v11.11) to my new print server in Ubuntu. The printing requests are not transferred from the HP-UX printing spooler queue to the new print-server. I think it could be the missing lpd socket (Port 515) which is not available on the new machine. I don't see it listing on the port (netstat -lpn).

I searched on Google for any soulutions, but I can't find anything that works.

Does anyone know what I have to do so that I can use the lpd protocol like in the old SLES9 distribution where it works fine at the moment?

I tried to install lpr but it doesn't open a listening Port on 515.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the cups-lpd daemon to support legacy LPD clients.  It is included in the cups package.  See 'man cups-lpd' for proper usage.

Comment: could you improve your answer with how op can achieve

Comment: No, I don't really think I can improve upon the documentation that has already been written.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. I installed xinetd and created a service for it.
I created a file called "cups-lpd" in "/etc/xinet.d/" with the following content:

```
service printer
{
        socket_type     = stream
        protocol        = tcp
        wait            = no
        user            = root
        #group          = sys
        #passenv                =
        server          = /usr/lib/cups/daemon/cups-lpd
        server_args     = -o document-format=application/octet-stream
}
```

This works fine. Now I have internal CUPS problems to solve :)

Thanks!